# How to separate cli parameters in nested structure by Python Click module

Tags: python

Can Click module integrated parameters which are divided at each function and use them to a function in Python?

The below code is my image code I want to construct(realize?).

- one.py

```py
class BasedClass:
  def __init__():
    pass

@click.command()
@click.option("--param1")
def make_instance1(param1):
    return BasedClass(param1)
```

- second.py

```py
from one import BasedClass

class InheritClass(BasedClass):
   def __init__():
      pass

@click.command()
@click.option("--param2")
def make_instance2(param2)
    return InheritClass(param1, param2) # I want to inherit param1 and param2.
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, what you want is Click's **Context**:

- https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/commands/#nested-handling-and-contexts

Basically, through *context* you can share info/state between commands.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your instruction helped me to get information I want.

Answer (score 0):

One `one.py`, the class `BasedClass` doesn’t take any arguments, but in the def `make_instance1` it returns `BasedClass(param1)` the error occurs in here.

Comment: The above code was image so it does not work. Thanks.